# Get payload in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, request

I want to read the payload in the `global.asax` file.
The payload in Chrome looks like [image: this].

When I want to read it in the `global.asax` I got a `Request.InputStream.Length` of 610. When I copy it to a MemoryStream the length of the memstream switches to 0.

```
public void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();
        Request.InputStream.CopyTo(memstream);
        memstream.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memstream))
        {
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

So at the end, `text` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to copy the input stream to another one I don't know but you could simply get it;

```
Request.InputStream.Seek(0,SeekOrigin.Begin);
using (Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
{
    using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var text = readStream.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Also, I don't know your requirements but it is not the proper approach to handle request. I would suggest you to get the request body in the action.

Comment: Even if I don't copy my input stream, var text stays empty. The receiveStream got a length of 610, like it should, but text stays empty.

Comment: This works fine for me, thanks a lot! But can you give me a short explanation of the code?

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to read the stream to the end, you should set the relative stream position to start.